# iOS how to pick colors for a hot/cold spectrogram when max magnitude is not known?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fft, color-mapping, spectrogram

I'm looking at the aurio touch sonogram example and see that it displays different FFT frequency bands, depending on their magnitude with color that ranges from blue to purple to red to white. When there's no sound, the graph is black. For low intensity sounds, different bands display blue. When the sound magnitude increases, the color becomes "hotter" - to red-white hot. This helps the user to easily see what's going on.

**I need suggestions on how to implement similar color-coding algorithm without knowing precisely what the maximum magnitude of the signal is going to be.**

[image: Aurio touch sonogram example]

I've tried to create something similar, but had limited success so far. This is the code that I'm using:

**pre- compute** the colors for different magnitudes of FFT

```
colorMapGreen = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:256];

        for(int i = 0; i<256; i ++)
        {

            [colorMapGreen setObject:[UIColor colorWithHue:0.2 saturation:1 brightness:(i/256.0) alpha:1] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

        }
```

The issue I'm running into is that I don't know what the maximum magnitude of the signal I will be looking at is. It varies wildly - from 12000 to 50000. If I try to tune my color mapping, it comes out to be either too dim or too bright and not really descriptive.

Here's how I'm trying to differentiate between different magnitude bands. I really want the low end (under 4000) to show up and be visible against other bands.

```
 magnitude=sqrt(magnitudes[i]);
        if(magnitude<4000)
        {
            //0 to 128
            index = magnitude*0.0213;

        }else if(magnitude < 15000)
        {
            //to 168
            index = magnitude*0.0112;

        }else if(magnitude < 30000)
        {
            //to 196
            index = magnitude*0.00653;
        }else if(magnitude < 100000)
        {
            //to 228
            index = magnitude*0.00228;

        }else if(magnitude < 10000000)
        {
            index = magnitude*0.0000256;

        }else
        {
            ((UIView*)[self.markerViews objectAtIndex:i]).backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
 ((UIView*)[self.markerViews objectAtIndex:i]).backgroundColor = [colorMapGreen objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]];
```

**Can anyone suggest an implementation of a color-mapping algorithm that would look closer to AurioTouch's hot-cold example?**

Here's what my code displays: 
[image]

Comment: Found this heat map code which has some math for displaying color range: https://github.com/gpolak/LFHeatMap

Answer (score 2):

Colormaps that need to cover a wide dynamic range are often colorized using scaled log(magnitude), rather than absolute magnitude, to index into the mapping table or equations.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you kinda have to do yourself; if the audio isn't realtime then you can normalize it, but otherwise you just have to give the user a gain knob.  If you are working with audio and `AudioUnit` is available, you could apply a severe compressor on the input to the FFT as a form of automatic gain correction.